# Adding a region in DXA and make component presentations editable

Tags: experience-manager, dxa

I am currently working on a layout in my DXA website.

I have created a new region, and i output this in my page view.
the resulting html is something like this

```
<div class="promotions" typeof="Region" resource="Promotions">
    <!-- Start Region: {title: "Promotions", allowedComponentTypes: [{schema: "xxx", template: "xxx"}], minOccurs: 0} -->
  (Component Presentation html)
</div>
```

So far, so good, my region renders fine, and in XPM, i can drag and drop content to my page region. The page reloads fine, and my added component presentations show up.

Now, I want to make the fields of my component presentations in the region editable, so i put the necessary markup tags, so my resulting html is this

```
<div class="promotions" typeof="Region" resource="Promotions">
    <!-- Start Region: {title: "Promotions", allowedComponentTypes: [{schema: "xxx", template: "xxx"}], minOccurs: 0} -->
  <div class="item"><!-- Start Component Presentation: {"ComponentID" : "xxx", "ComponentModified" : "xxx", "ComponentTemplateID" : "xxx", "ComponentTemplateModified" : "xxx", "IsRepositoryPublished" : false} -->
       (component presentation fields)
  </div>
  <div class="item"><!-- Start Component Presentation: {"ComponentID" : "xxx", "ComponentModified" : "xxx", "ComponentTemplateID" : "xxx", "ComponentTemplateModified" : "xxx", "IsRepositoryPublished" : false} -->
       (component presentation fields)
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, as soon as we add the "start componentpresentation" tags to the view html, the components become editable, but it looks like the region is no longer working (can't drag & drop any more components in this region any more).

I'm wondering if i'm doing something wrong here ?

I've tried to output the tags using the DXA helper functions (@Markup.Entity() & @Markup.Region()) and i also just 'hard-coded' the tags in my view, but the result stays the same.

Comment: I don't think the issue is in DXA, since the generated XPM markup looks OK to me. I initially though the issue would be in the occurrence constraints (minOccurs, maxOccurs) of the region: if there are already as many (or more) CPs in the region as allowed by maxOccurs, then you can't add CPs.  Note that maxOccurs is not explicitly specified in the XPM markup (nor can you get it specified in the STRI 1.0 implementation), but that should mean "unlimited" for XPM and so much for my theory...